# R markdown "magic number" error?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to knit following Rmardown:

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
date: '20 nov 2016 г '
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
---
## Next inline code produced error: `r 98809`
```

Error:

```
processing file: 111.Rmd
output file: 111.knit.md

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.91 ...e code produced error: 9.880910\^{}\{4\}}}

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF
Ошибка: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

If I edit the number and delete last "9" to looks likes this `r 9880` all going to be fine...

Is this a bug?

I'm testing on fresh R:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251  LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251    LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251 LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] magrittr_1.5    assertthat_0.1  htmltools_0.3.5 tools_3.3.2     yaml_2.1.13     tibble_1.2      Rcpp_0.12.7     stringi_1.1.2   rmarkdown_1.1   stringr_1.1.0   digest_0.6.10  
[12] evaluate_0.10  
>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modify the last line of your file:

```
## Next inline code produced error: `r format(98809)`
```

Comment: Yes, it works! But why? )

Comment: When number is large, let's say greater than 10000, and if the number is not the power of 10, one have to specify using the scientific-format or not.